# How do I set up an index on a pair of columns so that the values are tied together?

Tags: mysql, database, unique-index

I have a table with id, external_id and country_code columns.  I have two rules which I want the database to impose:

- Each External ID can only appear once per country code
- Each ID can only appear with at most one non-null External ID, and vice versa.

The first rule is easy enough - I add a unique multi-column index to external_id and country_code.  How do I get it to impose the second?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the second constraint exactly, but in this case it looks like a trigger tied to INSERT and UPDATE events would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds almost like your externalid should have a unique index too, if your saying that an externalid can only link to a single id.

Comment: it can only link to a single ID, but it can do so once for each different country code.